# What tools/programming languages do people use that support TDD?

Tags: paradigms, tdd

I want to get an idea of **What tools/programming languages people are using that supports Test Driven Development?**

Many Thanks, 
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I use c#, with visual studio, and it supports, both asp.net mvc2, wpf and almost any technology in the MS domain can be adjusted to TDD, and I'm sure that there is much more in the java domain as well

look in this sites for more information

[For Dot Net](http://www.nunit.org/)

[For Java](http://www.junit.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I use Java + JUnit + Eclipse.

Eclipse has a "quick fix" feature (Ctrl+1) that you can use to create necessary class/interface stubs to make your test code compile and run quickly.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? TDD is just: write the test, make it compile, make it fail, write minimum code to make it succeed, refactor, loop. Eclipse can help you make it compile with "quick fix", can make running tests easier with JUnit integration plugin, can help you do most of the refactorings. There are other plugins that can, for instance, continuously execute your tests in the background, but I never really used those. That's about it, no magic here.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET TDD is pretty easy now.

Visual studio 2010 natively supports TDD, it has its own build in testing framework.

Also .NET 4.0 has cool feature called Code Contracts which provide a language-agnostic way to express coding assumptions in .NET programs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx

The list of third party .NET TDD tools are here http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/testing/microsoft-.net-unit-testing-tools.html